# How to determine sample size of a bracketed ranked index

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, sampling

Would be so grateful for opinions here

I am tring to pay retailers for good customer service relative to their peers. I need to find out the minimum number of surveys required to be relatively sure (90%) that we are paying due to survey results and not chance, however there are a few odd factors.

I have a bunch of customer surveys scored between 1 and 10 - there are 71 dealers (these are like middle men - my company sells to them and they sell onto a retail customer) who have a total of around 25000 customers between them over a 6 month period. There are around 2500 customer surveys of this customer base in that same 6 month period. Each survey has 36 questions and the final total of the survey is an unweighted average of these questions. 
The surveys are unevenly distributed with some partners having over 50 surveys and many others less than 10. To mitigate this, I will average the scores over the surveys, and rank the partners in ascending order. I will then pay the top quartile one rate (every partner in the quartile gets the same payment), a lower rate for the second quartile and then lower again for the third and pay nothing for the dealers who are ranked in the lowest quartile.

Eg Dealer A has 20 surveys, and average score of these is 87. A score of 87 falls in the top 10 best average scores and thus Dealer A lands in the top quartile of the dealer group. We pay them the bonus for the top tier.

Dealer B has 5 surveys and average score is 72. This ranks in the bottom 25% of scores and therefore Dealer B does not get a customer service bonus.

Keeping in mind the clustered outcomes and relative ranking of this application, how can I find the minimum number of surveys required to be reasonably sure (say 90%) that the dealer's quartile bracket is not due to chance?